# how to save textbox values in scope variable angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i want store textbox value in my Values variable but its not save i don't know why anyone help me please??? i am new in angularjs  that's why i am here please help me   i want store values from textbox, i enter my textbox ff fff see below image, but i check my console file its show 'Site name' i think its get from my hard coded value but i want data from textbox

```
     $scope.form =  {
        site_name: 'Site name',
        street_address: 'Street address',
        city: 'City',
        state: 'state',
        country: 'country',
        zip_code: 'zip_code',
        phone_number: 'phone_number'

      };   
       $scope.addRow = function() {
        $scope.i++;
        $scope.array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.i; i++) {
            $scope.array.push(i);
        }
    }  
        var checkprofile = $scope.Profile.id;
         $(".alert").hide();    
          $scope.updateProfile = function () {   

               console.log( 'updateProfile');
             console.log( $scope.form);   
 $scope.Profile.addresses.push($scope.form);
            $scope.tempObject={full_name:$scope.Profile.full_name,
              mobile_number:$scope.Profile.mobile_number,
             company_name:$scope.Profile.company_name,
             designation: $scope.Profile.designation,    
            addresses: $scope.Profile.addresses,

            payment_info: $scope.Profile.payment_info

           };  

           $http.put(properties.customerupdate_path + "/"+checkprofile,$scope.tempObject).success(function (response) { 
           // window.location.href = '/customerprofile';
                });
            }
```

i click button after enter values 'ff' 'ff' 'ff' in my textboxes ...below code does not get data from textbox its get my above values i don't know why

```
  $scope.updateProfile = function () {    
           console.log( 'updateProfile');
         console.log( $scope.Values );
```

> //result  --> [Object { site_name="Site name",  street_address="Street
>   address",  city="City",  more...}]

```
}
```

HTML//

```
 <tr ng-repeat="lines in array">
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Values.site_name ' name='site_name'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Values.street_address ' name='street_address'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Values.city ' name='city'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Values.state ' name='state'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Values.country ' name='country'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Values.zip_code ' name='zip_code'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Values.phone_number ' name='phone_number'></td>                                        
</tr>
```

Update Profile

[image]

Comment: Looks like $scope.values is a list but you are using it as an object in ng model

Comment: i want object....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.values = {
    site_name: 'Site name',
    street_address: 'Street address',
    city: 'City'
};

<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='values.site_name ' name='site_name'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='values.street_address ' name='street_address'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='values.city ' name='city'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='values.state ' name='state'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='values.country ' name='country'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Values.zip_code ' name='zip_code'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='values.phone_number ' name='phone_number'></td>
</tr>
```

You don't use an Array to store your variable, but an object.

Comment: Object {}   array are blank  when i check      console.log( $scope.values);

Comment: Did you change your `ng-model` ? Never use capital letters as first letters of a variable name. look, in the `td` you can see that `ng-model="values."` instead of `ng-model="Values."`

Comment: Please see my edit. If you do this and your inputs are empty, you didn't bind your controller to your view properly.

Comment: there is hard coded values  'Site name', like store but does not store textbox value when i change  'Site namemyname', from textbox

Comment: Ok so I don't understand anything you're saying. **[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12448/)** and try to understand what you did wrong.

Comment: i enter my textbox 'ff ff ff '   but its store  'Site name'  hard code value.. check image , i enter my textbox ff ff but store Site name

Comment: I am here to help you, but you need to do some work on your own you know. I updated the fiddle to fit your needs, no work yourself and apply it to your problem.

Comment: I EDIT MY QUESTION check

Comment: I GAVE YOU A WORKING FIDDLE check

Comment: I give up. At this point I can't do anything more to help you. If you can't look at my working example and apply it to your code, i'm not useful anymore.

Comment: thanks for your support ... there is problem is i update my record click button   your button is working but when i click my button   <button type="submit" >Update Profile</button>  not working

Comment: I don't see this button anywhere in the code you provided. If you want a real help, either you give the full code, or you create a working JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over an object. Your model should be an array in order to support this. The rest of your code is just fine. Replace your Values with:

```
 $scope.Values =  [
     {
       site_name: 'Site name',
       street_address: 'Street address',
       city: 'City',
       state: 'state',
       country: 'country',
       zip_code: 'zip_code',
       phone_number: 'phone_number'
    }, 
    { //next object
    }
];
```